# SDL_PollEvent pauses thread

Tags: c++, macos, sdl, sdl-2

I encountered a strange bug using SDL_PollEvent to detect an SDL_Quit event. Whenever I click the X on the window it works fine and ends the program but whenever I hold down the X button it pauses the execution of the program. Any idea why this is happening, and is there a way around it?

Here is my code:

main.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

int main() {

    Game* game = nullptr;

    while(game->running) {
     
    game->checkForClose();

    return 0;

}
```

Game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H_
#define GAME_H_

#include "SDL.h"

class Game {
public:

    Game();
    ~Game();

    void checkForClose();

    static bool running;
    static SDL_Event event;

};

#endif
```

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>

void Game::checkForClose() {

SDL_PollEvent(&event);
switch (event.type) {
    case SDL_QUIT:
        running = false;
        std::cout << "Program Terminated!" << std::endl;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

**P.S.** I am on MacOS

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives.

Comment: Although SDL is designed to be cross-platform and to behave the same way on all platforms, in my experience, it does sometimes behave a bit differently on different platforms. Therefore, it may be worth mentioning on which platform (e.g. operating system) you have experienced this problem.

Comment: If you're on windows, take a look at https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/issues/1059 . TLDR it is how it is on windows. which may or may not be fixed some time in future. If it is absolutely necessary for you, there are some ways to work around that, with various levels of windows-specific trickery.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I am on MacOS X